# Excel convert column into row

Tags: excel

I want to convert Column data into 4 rows in excel.
I have data like this

```
A  B  C  D
1
2
.
.
20000
```

ABCD are columns, only A has value till 1 to 20000.
I want to equally divide 4 values ABCD(1234), ABCD (5678)
How i can do in excel ?

Comment: 4 rows...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*4-4+COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

drag it in the same row 3 times and down

```
1   2   3   4 Drag in the same row 3 columns
5   6   7   8   and down in each column 
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24
25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32
33  34  35  36
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Sub divideby4()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 5
    Range("D" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value / 4
    Range("C" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value / 4
    Range("B" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value / 4
    Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value / 4
Next i
End Sub
```

Before and after:

[image: BeforeAfter]

Alternatively:

```
Sub equallydivideby4()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

j = 1
For i = 1 To 10
    Range("D" & i).Value = Range("A" & j + 3).Value
    Range("C" & i).Value = Range("A" & j + 2).Value
    Range("B" & i).Value = Range("A" & j + 1).Value
    Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & j).Value
    j = j + 4
Next i
End Sub
```

Produces (Before/After):

[image: Before/After]

Comment: I want to do in excel

Comment: This is excel. Create a macro and run it.

Comment: i dont have developer option in my excel

Comment: Right click on "View", click "Customize the Ribbon", Check off "Developer" in the right side column.

Comment: But you can also access Macros right from the View tab. View -> Macros -> Create